# Font is vertically centered on MacOS, but not on Windows

Tags: html, css

I'm using a custom font which I imported like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Circular Std';
    src: url('CircularStd-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('CircularStd-Bold.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

I'm developing on MacOS - and with every browser on this OS the font is displayed perfectly.
Somehow on Windows, even with the newest version of Chrome and every other browser, the font is not vertically centered, but rather aligned to the top.

How so?

Answer (score 1):

With:

```
font-display: swap;
```

It gives the font face an extremely ***small*** block period and an ***infinite*** swap period.

To answer your question, try using:

```
font-display: auto;
```

REASON:
The reason why you want to use **auto** instead of **swap** is because

1. It's very good practice
2. The font display strategy is defined by the user agent, when using auto

So whether you're on Windows or Mac it will automatically change to your preference

Hope that cleared things up for you!